# Random Corrupted Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Jenkins job that builds a Rails 4 application upon a code push to SVN.  Occasionally, during the `bundle install` the bundler will fail with the following complaint ::

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/cache/SOME-RANDOM-GEM.gem. It may be corrupted.
```

This happens on random builds, for random gems that have worked multiple times before.  In order to work around it, I have been doing ::

```
--AS ROOT 
gem uninstall NAME_OF_GEM
gem install NAME_OF_GEM -v 'VERSION'
gem bundle install
```

Sometimes this process works and Jenkins will be able to successfully invoke and complete the `bundle install`.  Other times it will make it past the previously 'corrupted' gem, only to now have another gem be 'corrupted'.

Does anybody have any experience or advice with this issue?

**Details**

- RHEL 6.6
- Rails 4.2.0
- Ruby 2.2.0p0

Comment: Looks like it's calling askpass because it would like that you authenticate in SSH somehow. Is it maybe because you are trying to download a Gem from an SSH accessed repo? It might be a rating limit that you are encountering, that would explain the randomness. If you are accessing a repo via SSH you could set up a keypair to avoid using the password and solving your issue (maybe :)).

Comment: @mat_jack1 Thanks for the reply.  I looked at our Gemfile and it doesn't appear that we're accessing any secured Repos.  We're accessing RubyGems.org and 3 Repos internal to our company, but we access all of them via straight http.